# Why my Javascript content not visible in webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-development-server

I am new to javascript. I was trying to make some quiz game using html, css and JS.
In quiz I want timer for 1 minute. I wrote seperated code for timer and templates. Timer was working fine.

But when I merged both code timer is not visible. Though after completion of 1 minute it gives message 'time's up'. I used positioning properties and tried different positions but still it is not visible.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .score
      {
        position:absolute;
        left:900;
      }
      #whole
      {
        background-color:black;
        color:white;
        width:80%;
        height:70%;
        position:relative;
        top:45;
        left:95;
        border:4px solid black;
      }
      .optns
      {
        width:40%;
        height:5%
      }
      #question
      {
        color:black;
        background-color:#f2f2f2;
        width:99%;
        height:20%;
        position:absolute;
        top:35;
        left:5;
      }
      .optn1
      {
        position:absolute;
        top:190;
        left:120;
      }
      .optn2
      {
        position:absolute;
        top:230;
        left:120;
      }
      .optn3
      {
        position:absolute;
        top:270;
        left:120;
      }
      .optn4
        {
        position:absolute;
        top:310;
        left:120;
      }
      .prev
      {
        position:absolute;
        down:80px;
        left:200px;
      }
      .next
      {
        position:absolute;
        down:80px;
        right:200px;
      }
      #timer
      {
        position:absolute;
        top:1000px;
        background-color:pink;
        color:blue;
        font-family:cursive;
        z-index:9999;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id=whole>
      <center>TIMER HERE</center>
      <script>
        var fixed=new Date();
        var fixedsecond=fixed.getSeconds();
        var fixedmin=fixed.getMinutes();
        function changetime()
        {
          var current=new Date();
          var currentsecond=current.getSeconds();
          var currentmin=current.getMinutes();
          var m=currentmin-fixedmin;
          var s=(currentsecond-fixedsecond);
          if(s<0)
          {
            s=s+60
            m=m-1;
          }
          if(m>=1)
          {
            clearInterval(t);
            prompt("TIME IS UP");
          }
          document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML="<center id=timer><h1>"+m+":"+s

          +"</center></h1>";
        }
        var t=setInterval(changetime,1000);
      </script>
      <span class="score">SCORE</span>
      <div id=question>
        Question here
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="optn1 optns">OPTION 1</button>
    <button class="optn2 optns">OPTION 2</button>
    <button class="optn3 optns">OPTION 3 </button>
    <button class="optn4 optns">OPTION 4</button>
    <button class=prev>PREVIOUS</button>
    <button class="next">NEXT</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The center tag inside <script> ,with "document.getElementById" has id=timer.

Comment: You are reference to `null` (see console output). Note, the [`<center>` tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp) is deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) change

```
<center id="timer">TIMER HERE</center>
```

with this:

```
<div id="timer">TIMER HERE</div>
```

2) also you need to change this:

```
document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "<center id=timer><h1>" + m + ":" + s
```

with this:

```
document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=m+":"+s;
```

3) your CSS is bugged, change:

```
#timer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1000px;
  background-color: pink;
  color: blue;
  font-family: cursive;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

with that:

```
#timer
{
text-align: center;
background-color:pink;
color:fff;
font-family:cursive;
}
```

now you can see your timer...

Answer (score 1):

You call `document.getElementById("timer")` but this element does not exists in HTML yet. You need to have this element in your HTML or create it in document  via JavaScript.

Try something like this:

```
<div id="timer">TIMER HERE</center>
```

And JS:

```
document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = m + ":" + s;
```

Also - You should not use `<center>` as it's deprecated.

Comment: In addition to that you do not need to include the outer element in `innerHtml` again. That's why it's called so: `document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = '<h1>' + m + ':' + s + '</h1>';`

Answer (score 0):

You should see the javascript error directly from Web Developer Console using any browsers (Safari, Chrome, etc.).
This code fails at this line

```
document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML
```

There's no element with id "timer".

Answer (score 0):

You are using "whole" as id in HTML but calling "timer" id in javascript.

Update the id in script like below:

```
document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML
```

with

```
document.getElementById("whole").innerHTML
```